# Use PropertyChanged or WeakSubscribe?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

What is the best way to track a property change?

I have the following concerns why I can't make a decision.
- PropertyChanged can prevent garbage collection from collecting a ViewModel that uses its own PropertyChanged event?
- Could WeakSubscribe be gone at any moment in time when using to track ViewModels own property changes?

Did anyone test this or just know the answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you won't hit problems if you use `PropertyChanged` strong subscriptions.... However, there are some cases where this can lead to "leaks" - e.g. if you subscribe on a sub-object which has a longer lifetime than a "normal" ViewModel (e.g. a singleton service).

To be safe, though, you can use `WeakSubscribe` - as long as you store a reference to the returned token from the `WeakSubscribe` call in a member field in your view, then this will ensure that the subscription remains active for at least as long as your View is in memory.

Regardless of strong or weak, one additional thing to aim for ... is to try to release the event subscription (either strong or weak) as early as you can. This will help prevent event callbacks being fired after the View has disappeared.

Comment: Tnx for the explanation. So a PropertyChanged event within its own ViewModel won't keep the ViewModel from collecting by the garbage collection. Good to know.